# I have created CHECK constraint but receiving error message

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create sequence student_studentid_seq
increment by 10
start with 100
nocycle;

create table student 
(studentid number(10),
name varchar2(30) not null,
ss# number(9) unique,
gpa number(2,3) not null,
  constraint student_studentid_pk PRIMARY KEY (studentid),
  constraint student_gpa_ck CHECK (GPA >= 0) );

insert into student (studentid, name, ss#, gpa)
              values(student_studentid_seq.NEXTVAL,'Draze Katan', 323456789,1);

receiving error message:
Error starting at line 29 in command:
insert into student (studentid, name, ss#, gpa)
              values(student_studentid_seq.NEXTVAL,'Draze Katan', 323456789,1)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
01438. 00000 -  "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"
*Cause:    When inserting or updating records, a numeric value was entered
           that exceeded the precision defined for the column.
*Action:   Enter a value that complies with the numeric column's precision,
           or use the MODIFY option with the ALTER TABLE command to expand
           the precision.
```

So it appears error message is for next constraint:constraint student_gpa_ck CHECK (GPA >= 0) );
In insert statement if I enter '0' for GPA raw will be inserted but anything more I will receive error message.

This is one of my exercise questions, I can't figure out. I just need hint where mistake is not full resolution. Please if you could help me out.

Comment: Why are you using number(10) for the primary key. It should be integer. Number is slower.

Comment: @JoeLove Number is slower? Could you elaborate on that with some supporting data?

Comment: Why `number(2,3)` for GPA? That is the problem (not a "check constraint"). What did you mean by it? If you meant it to be numbers like 3.84 and 2.33, then you need `number(3,2)`. 3 means "three significant digits" and 2 means "... of which the last two are after the decimal point."

Comment: Thank you so much for help guys!!!

Comment: My mistake, I had postgresql on the brain and was thinking numeric vs integer.

Comment: And I'm a certified oracle DBA.. oops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in the way you create the table, in particular in the column `GPA`.

You are using `number(2, 3)`, which looks like "build a number with 2 total digits and 3 decimal digits".

In [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021) you find a better explanation about the `NUMBER` data type, its attributes and what things like `number(2,3)` mean:

> Specify a fixed-point number using the following form:
>
> NUMBER(p,s) where:
>
> p is the precision, or the maximum number of significant decimal
>   digits, where the most significant digit is the left-most nonzero
>   digit, and the least significant digit is the right-most known digit.
>   Oracle guarantees the portability of numbers with precision of up to
>   20 base-100 digits, which is equivalent to 39 or 40 decimal digits
>   depending on the position of the decimal point.
>
> s is the scale, or the number of digits from the decimal point to the
>   least significant digit. The scale can range from -84 to 127.
>
> Positive scale is the number of significant digits to the right of the
>   decimal point to and including the least significant digit.
>
> Negative scale is the number of significant digits to the left of the
>   decimal point, to but not including the least significant digit. For
>   negative scale the least significant digit is on the left side of the
>   decimal point, because the actual data is rounded to the specified
>   number of places to the left of the decimal point. For example, a
>   specification of (10,-2) means to round to hundreds.
>
> Scale can be greater than precision, most commonly when e notation is
>   used. When scale is greater than precision, the precision specifies
>   the maximum number of significant digits to the right of the decimal
>   point. For example, a column defined as NUMBER(4,5) requires a zero
>   for the first digit after the decimal point and rounds all values past
>   the fifth digit after the decimal point.

For example:

```
SQL> create table tabError( a number (2, 3));

Table created.

SQL> insert into tabError values (1);
insert into tabError values (1)
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column


SQL> insert into tabError values (0.1);
insert into tabError values (0.1)
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column


SQL> insert into tabError values (0.01);

1 row created.
```

If you need 2 digits for the integer part and 3 for decimals, you need `number(5, 3)` or, according to Mathguy's comment, if you need numbers with one integer digit and 2 decimals, you need `number(3,2)`.

Comment: Oracle doesn't refuse to create such nonsens? Strange.

Comment: @dnoeth I added a more recent link that better explains, among the others, what Oracle does in such a case

Comment: @dnoeth - Why is that "nonsense"? `NUMBER(2,3)` is the correct data type for numbers from 0.001 to 0.099. It simply means "scale" of three decimal places to the right of the decimal point, and "precision" of only two significant digits. The OP using this incorrectly (thinking it means something different) doesn't make it "nonsense".

Comment: @mathguy: to be honest, the first version of my answer was something like "number(2, 3) does not make sense", hence the comment

Comment: OK, got it. I guess the OP needs `number(3,2)`. I don't know if GPA is a common term in other countries, but it is very common in the US, where grades are up to 4 (or sometimes 4.33 or 5) and GPA is always reported with two decimal places.

Comment: @mathguy: I confused NUMBER with DECIMAL, in fact I never noticed that NUMBER can be defined like that.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot for help. Since for one integer and two decimals I will need (3,2) is there are reason for that? Just to make sense out of it, Thank you again.